# pass json data to JQGrid

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Hello eveyone am new to mvc. i want to display every groupname in a seperate row,group  names are retrieved from active directry.those group names need to show into a jqgrid.with  my code am able to show all groupnames in a single row but not in multiple rows with id.and  also selected ltems to move into another jagrid.
here is my model class

```
public class AdGroups
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List< string> GroupName { get; set; }      
}
```

in the below "list ls" am able to get all domain groups in ls.
Here is my action method,here my controller name is JqgridController.

```
public JsonResult DomainNames()
{
    AdGroups adg = new AdGroups();
    List<AdGroups> li = new List<AdGroups>();
    List<string> ls = new List<string>();
    ls = GetADGroups("xyz.com");         
   var jsonData = new
    {
        rows = (
          from ct in li
          select new
          {
             id = ct.GroupName
           }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

my view is like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Domain Names</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#list1").jqGrid({
url: '@Url.Action("DomainNames", "JQGrid")',
datatype: 'json',
rowNum: 5,
rowList: [10, 20, 30],
sortname: 'GroupName',
sortorder: 'desc',
viewrecords: true,
mtype: 'GET',
colNames: ['GroupName'],
colModel: [
{ name: 'GroupName', index: 'GroupName', align: 'left', sortable: false }
]
});
});
</script>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="list1"></table>
<div id="pager1"></div>
</td>           
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The model should be like :

```
public class AdGroups
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public List<string> GroupName { get; set; }  
     public string DomainGroup {get;set;}    
}
```

And the action method should be like :

```
List<AdGroups> li = new List<AdGroups>();
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls = GetADGroups("xyz.com");
for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
{
     AdGroups adg = new AdGroups();
     adg.DomainGroup = ls[i].ToString();
     li.Add(adg);
}

return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```